# Hacking UINavigationBar / Apple approval

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

Here is a screenshot from Evernote. It appears to have (but i might be wrong) a custom UINavigationBar as well as a custom UITabBar.

[image: evernote sceenshot]

A quick glance at the apps on my phone shows i could use a screenshot of Instagram, Path, DailyBooth, ...

[From the docs:-](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html)

> Because managing the navigation bar is
>   the responsibility of the navigation
>   controller, direct modification of the
>   navigation bar itself is considered
>   off limits for the most part.

Does Apple regard this kind of thing as grounds for AppStore refusal?

Comment: You are correct in saying that lots of apps are using this kind of thing these days; here's the library most of them are probably using: https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay

Comment: @Krypton, ah thanks - didn't know about. My personal feeling is that this is a very useful interface component, but is it safe to use?

Comment: Seeing the number of live public apps that are using it, I'd have said it was a-ok to use. As the answer below states, if you directly went ahead and tinkered with the UINavigationBar and it's deep inner workings, then Apple would likely disapprove. The link I posted is pretty cool though - if I had a need for something like that I'd use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a distinction between "custom" navigation bars and using private methods.

Apple prevent you from directly modifying the navigation bar by make a lot of the required methods private or properties read-only. If you were to modify a read-only property or use a private undocumented method your application would be rejected (Apple automatically analyse code upon submission to detect for this sort of thing).

However, there's nothing to stop you from implementing your own `UINavigationBar` equivalent, or customising it using publicly available SDK methods. The issue then becomes whether your application strays too far from the Human Interface Guidelines: although to be honest, Apple are generally fairly flexible on that.

Whilst I wouldn't necessarily recommend this, I've worked on one app where we rolled our own navigation controller because we had some animation and transition requirements that we couldn't achieve with Apple's own class. As long as you're not calling anything untoward or drastically going against the HIGs, you're generally fine.

Comment: It seems to me that private methods are not required, but you must insert subviews into the tabBar hierarchy at the correct places and reposition the tabBar's component subviews. This (i guess) relies on the makeup of tabBar not changing in the future, which is extremely fragile. If i were Apple, i wouldn't allow it, but if other apps are doing it, i want to keep up.